# Django form updating after adding data to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm building a form for user's to run a query on a database.  The model is called Sample and the user is selecting the names they want to include in the query results.  In this case the name field is unique but other fields done the same way aren't.

**Form.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Sample

class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    samples = Sample.objects.all()
    names = [(s.id, s.name) for s in samples]
    initial = [c[0] for c in names]
    Rock_Names = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          choices=names,
                                          initial=initial,
                                          label='Name')
```

The problem I'm having is when a new sample has been added the form won't update with that sample name until I restart the server.  I have a list view for all samples and it updates with the new sample fine.  I've tried running `Sample.objects.update()` after the new sample is saved, but that didn't help.  Is there a way to force this to update?  Is there a better way to build a query form?

**Edit** Okay, I thought through this and realized it is a more basic object oriented programming problem.  The form is created using class attributes defined with the class definition (at server restart) and not when an instance is created (when the page reloads).  I don't think I want to rerun the form creation every time the page loads (such as moving to instance attributes in an init method), so I moved the form creation to a function that is called at class definition and through a method I can call when I add data.  The new code looks like:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Sample

def create_form():
    samples = Sample.objects.all()
    names = [(s.id, s.name) for s in samples]
    initial = [c[0] for c in names]
    Rock_Names = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          choices=names,
                                          initial=initial,
                                          label='Name')
    return Rock_Names

class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    Rock_Names = create_form()

   def update_form():
      Rock_Names = create_form()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a choice field with dynamic choices, setting them in the `__init__` method is the recommended approach.

In your case, you can probably simply use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` instead of a `MultipleChoiceField`:

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):

    rock_names = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          queryset=Sample.objects.all(),
                                          label='Name')
```

To get `Sample.name` as label, you either have to give `Sample` a `__str__` method:

```
class Sample(models.Model):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Or create and use a subclass of `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with a custom `label_from_instance` method:

```
class SampleMultipleChoiceField(MultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name


class SampleForm(forms.Form):

    rock_names = SampleMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          queryset=Sample.objects.all(),
                                          label='Name')
```

On a side note, the common convention is to write class attributes in lower case.